# PHP ReflectionClass method does not exists

Tags: php, reflection, laravel-5.4

I am trying to instantiate a class by reflection like this:

```
$class = new ReflectionClass('App\\Widgets\\TestWidget');
```

But that always throws a ReflectionException with this message:

```
[2017-02-20 19:05:25] local.ERROR: ReflectionException while trying to reflect C:\Users\Asier\PhpstormProjects\web-cms\app\Widgets\TestWidget\TestWidget.php
Class App\Widgets\TestWidget implements Widget {

/**
 * It is called when the widget is used in a template to render it.
 * @return string
 */
public function render() {
    return "Hello world from TestWidget";
}

/**
 * Returns the widget's name
 * @return string
 */
public static function getWidgetName() {
    return "TestWidget";
}

/**
 * Returns the widget's info
 * @return string|array
 */
public static function getWidgetInfo() {
    return "";
}

/**
 * It is called when the widget is uploaded to make the proper setup for it if needed
 * @return void
 */
public static function setup() {

}

public function dummy() does not exist
```

And this is the class:

```
<?php
namespace App\Widgets;


class TestWidget implements Widget {

/**
 * It is called when the widget is used in a template to render it.
 * @return string
 */
public function render() {
    return "Hello world from TestWidget";
}

/**
 * Returns the widget's name
 * @return string
 */
public static function getWidgetName() {
    return "TestWidget";
}

/**
 * Returns the widget's info
 * @return string|array
 */
public static function getWidgetInfo() {
    return "";
}

/**
 * It is called when the widget is uploaded to make the proper setup for it if needed
 * @return void
 */
public static function setup() {

}

public function dummy() {}

}
```

If I delete the last method (dummy), then it says the same "does not exists" with the last method in the class.

Any ideas?

P.D.: Using Laravel 5.4.

**EDIT:** Okay guys. Problem solved. I was just tired. I have a method with a regular expression that matches a script and gets its class name and turns out that suddenly it stopped working as expected and the group returned almost the entire script as a string instead of the proper class name.

It is fixed now as follows:

```
/**
 * Returns the class name of the given php script
 * @param $script real path to the script
 * @return mixed
 */
public function className($script) {
    $match = preg_match('/class ([A-Za-z0-9_]{1,}) +.* {/ism', file_get_contents($script), $className);
    return $className[1];
}
```

Thanks all for giving it a try. And excuse me.

Comment: Is the class you are trying to reflect imported in your current page ?

Comment: Can you please format the code and add the entire error message?

Comment: That is actually the ReflectionException message. I will post the trace as soon as I get to work but it does not give a single clue...

Comment: I might have a silly guess. Could it be because the class has no constructor defined?

Comment: @Nicolas Oh. Yes of course. I included it.

Comment: No. It's not the constructor.